# Maximize income and calculate maximum gross profit with service charge

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics

> A $300$-room hotel is filled to capacity every night at $\$80$ a room. For each $\$1$ in rent, $3$ fewer rooms are rented. How much should the management charge for each room to maximize income? If each room rented costs management $\$20$ service per day, what is the maximum gross profit?

For the question, "How much should the management charge for each room to maximize income," I obtained the correct answer:

> $$(80+x)(300-3x)=P$$ $$-3x^2+60x+24000=P$$ $$x=\dfrac{-60}{-6}=10$$ $$\text{Management should charge}\; \$90$$.

For the question, "If each room rented costs management $\$20$ service per day, what is the maximum gross profit," my answer of $\$19200$ was incorrect. The correct answer was $\$18900$. My work:

> $$(60+x)(300-3x)=P$$ $$-3x^2+120x+18000=P$$ $$x=\dfrac{-120}{-6}=20$$ $$80\cdot240=\$19200\;\text{as the maximum gross profit}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251768/how-to-maximize-profit-in-this-equation

Comment: Your final answer is correct, but there is a constant missing in $-3x^2 + 120x = P$.

Comment: @LinAlg No, my answer is wrong...

Comment: I still disagree. The accepted answer assumes the question asks for the "gross profit if the price is not adjusted accordingly", while the current question clearly mentions the "maximum gross profit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to calculate how many rooms will be rented at $90 per night.

(*rate - service charge*) × *number of rooms*